# Can we have the sequence of polynomials that behave in this way?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

Suppose that we define the sequence of polynomials in such a way that the "next" polynomial in the sequence has the same coefficients as the one "before" except that the "next" one is one degree greater than the one "before" and so has one coefficient more.

To be precise, define $p_1(a)=b_1a+b_0$, now define $p_2(a)=b_2a^2+b_1a+b_0$, $p_3$ would be $p_3(a)=b_3a^3+b_2a^2+b_1a+b_0$, if we proceed in the same spirit we arrive at this recursive definition:

1) $p_1(a)=b_1a+b_0$

2) $p_{n+1}(a)=p_n(a)+b_{n+1}a^{n+1}$

I have the following questions:

> 1) Is it true that for every $a$ there exist sequence $b_0,b_1,...b_n,...$ such that $p_n(a)$ is prime for every $n$?
>
> 2) Is it true that for every $a$ there exist infinite number of sequences $b_{0,k},b_{1,k},...,b_{n,k},...$ such that $p_{n,k}(a)$ is prime for every choice of $n$ and $k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are true by [Dirichlet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions). Really, take some $a$; now let $b_0$ be any prime number (not equal to $a$, in case if $a$ itself happens to be prime) - that's infinitely many possible values already. Now $b_1a+b_0$ for various $b_1$ is an an arithmetic progression, and with $a$ and $b_0$ being coprime, it contains infinitely many primes, so your sequence of polynomials can be continued in infinitely many ways. Any prime thus obtained is greater than $a$ and consequently coprime to $a$ or any power thereof, so we may continue in the same way with $b_2a^2+b_1a+b_0$ and so on.

Comment: I do not understand how we can jump from $p_1(a)$ to $p_2(a)$ and then from $p_2(a)$ to $p_3(a)$ and so on... if those jumps include in itself adding new power of $a$ and a new coefficient in such a way that the sequence defined in that way is not arithmetic progression? Are you really sure that your argument works? (It could be that I am missing something.)

Comment: Well, $b_2a^2+b_1a+b_0$ for various $b_2$ (and constant $a$ and everything else) is nothing but an arithmetic progression, right?

Comment: But how do you know that it must always be the case that we can choose in such a way that $a^{n+1}$ and $p_n(a)$ will be coprime? Okay, it could be that I do not understand your argument.

Comment: $p_n(a)$ is prime and greater than $a$; of course it is coprime to $a$ (and, consequently, to any power of $a$).

Comment: Suppose $a$ is prime. What are the infinite many choices $b_0,...,b_n$, such that $p_n(a)=a$ for all $n$ ?

Comment: $b_0$ is any prime other than $a$ itself. $b_1$ is any of the infinitely many values of $k$ that produce primes in the arithmetic progression $k\cdot a+b_0$, and so on. Oh, and it is not like $p_n(a)=a$ (where did that come from?) - it is just that $p_n(a)$ is prime.

Comment: You should omit the confusing statement "many choices already" and clarify that $b_0$ is a prime different from $a$, $\ \ \ b_1\times a+b_0$ another prime (obviously different from $a$) and so on.

Comment: Since we have infinite many choices in every step, we can solve $2)$ as well.

Comment: If you edit your answer in this manner, I will upvote it.

Comment: I already **did** say that $b_0$ should be chosen not equal to $a$. _Sapienti sat_.

Comment: For clarification it could only be added in the answer that we choose $(b_0,b_1,...,b_n)$ in such a way that $p_n(a)$ is a prime number chosen in such a way that it is not some prime number that is present in the prime factorization of $a^{n+1}$.

Comment: OK, I'll add that.